# Cannot install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error, lwc-dev-server

When running `sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server` on Sonoma 14 OSX, it returns either:

> Warning: @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @lwc/engine@1.2.2: Use
> @lwc/engine-dom instead Error:
> /usr/local/lib/sf/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js add
> @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest --non-interactive
> --mutex=file:/Users/john/.local/share/sf/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=/Users/john/Library/Caches/sf/yarn --check-files exited with code 127

or it returns:

> Warning: @salesforce/lwc-dev-server > @oclif/config@1.18.17: Package
> no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support
> for more info. Error: /usr/local/lib/sf/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
> add @salesforce/lwc-dev-server@latest --non-interactive
> --mutex=file:/Users/john/.local/share/sf/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=/Users/john/Library/Caches/sf/yarn --check-files exited with code 127

Response from https://www.npmjs.com/support - "We can confirm the @oclif/config package has been deprecated."  So...not sure what good that is.

Attempted solutions:

```
Reinstalled SFDX  
Reinstalled Node/NPM
Ran npm install -g node-gyp
```

Any ideas? Thanks